# How to get only the date from DateTime information in sqlserver?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following sql query that returns the DateTime-formatted information in Month format like December or Novermber:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID) AS [Total Number of Taken Quizzes], dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete) 
                      AS Month
FROM         dbo.UserQuiz INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.UserQuiz.Username = dbo.employee.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, DATENAME(Month, dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete)
```

I want just to get the date in whatever format such as: mm-dd-yyyy. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID) AS [Total Number of Taken Quizzes], dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, convert(varchar,dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete,110 ) 
                      AS Month
FROM         dbo.UserQuiz INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.UserQuiz.Username = dbo.employee.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionName,convert(varchar,dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete,110)
```

Comment: what does 110 mean in convert(varchar,dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete,110 )?

Comment: It means USA Format (mm-dd-yyyy) check the following link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast(convert(varchar, datefield, 112) as datetime)
```

This for returning as datetime, if you want a string - do only convert with proper format number instead of 112

For server version 2008+ you can use more simple and fast in `GROUP BY` clause construction like

```
CAST(dbo.UserQuiz.DateTimeComplete as DATE)
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the above answer? I mean what is the difference between 110 and 112?

Comment: Difference in time of the answer - my answer if first, difference between 112 and 110 - that 112 returns date as yyyymmdd (sortable format) and 110 as mm-dd-yyyy - if you want just strings - use 110, if you wand to operate with date value (sorting, parsing, diff with other date) - use 112

Answer (score 0):

I would probably return just the date as a datetime value and leave the formatting job to the client application. You can reset the time and day part of a datetime like this:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, your_datetime_value), 0)
```

The above expression returns the midnight of the first of the corresponding month, e.g. for `2011-12-26 16:49:53.487` it would produce `2011-12-01 00:00:00.000`.